# Using "Python" in Selenium WebDriver getting this message: object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I am using `Selenium WebDriver` in Python in `Pycharm`, where I am using a class having 2 test functions.

```
class goodsweb(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        driverlocation ="/Users/new/Documents/Learning/Drivers/selenium-2.53.1/py/selenium/webdriver/chromedriver"
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driverlocation
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverlocation)

    def test_Test1(self):
        self.EmailEntry = input("Please Enter Email Address: ")
        self.EmailAddress.send_keys(self.EmailEntry)
        self.Password.clear()
        self.password='12345678'
        self.Password.send_keys(self.password)

    def test_Test2(self):
        self.LoginEmail = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sign_form-default']//div[1]/input[@type='email']")
        self.LoginEmail.clear()
        self.LoginEmail.click()
        self.LoginEmail.send_keys(self.EmailEntry)

        self.LoginPassword = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sign_form-default']//div[1]/input[@type='password']")
        self.LoginPassword.clear()
        self.LoginPassword.click()
        self.LoginPassword.send_keys(self.password)
```

Now What I want is get access of `EmailEntry` and `Password` of `test_Test1` in `test_Test2`

Whenever I am running the code, I am having this error:

> AttributeError: 'goodsweb' object has no attribute 'EmailEntry'

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback). There are other useful informations

Comment: where is your EmailEntry field ?
It can't accessible in goodsweb class.
Declare in this class or define as static.

Comment: @furas It was very a long code, so I have just entered main things which were required for this problem.

Comment: @Hiten I have defined it as static, and it worked. but my question is, is that good practice?

Comment: I have got another question, How Can I call any fucntion, means that only specific function on other script. Means If there are 2 fucntions i.e. Function1 and Function2 in ClassA of ScriptA, I want to access only and only Function2 in ScriptB.

Comment: you should show atleast few last lines of Traceback - there is information which line of code makes problem. It helps to see where problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where is your EmailEntry field ?

It can't accessible in goodsweb class. Declare in this class or define as static so you can use in any other classes.

If you want to use one field in other classes or function then you have to define field as static.

For functions the concept is same. You can defined function as static like

```
public static void main(){
     // your logic
}
```

For python ::

```
class MyClass(object):
    def the_static_method(x):
        print x
    the_static_method = staticmethod(the_static_method)

MyClass.the_static_method(2) # outputs 2
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and its Python..not Java.